# Does a dense submodule of a free module always contain a basis? 

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, hilbert-spaces, modules, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Let $R$ be a completed normed ring, eg Banach algebra. Suppose that $F$ is a free $R$-module of infinite rank with a norm defined by the square root of sum of all norms of its components. If $F'$ is a dense submodule of $F$, does $F'$ contain a basis of $F$?

Comment: The square root of the sum is not a norm. You need the square root of the sum of squares of norms.
Next if $F'$ contains a basis of $F$, it is equal to $F$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not so.
Let $R=\mathbb C$ and consider the module $F$ to be the finite sequences in $\ell^2({\mathbb C})$.
Let $F'$ be the submodule of all sequences $(z_n)$ with $\sum_nz_n=0$.
Then $F'$ is dense in $F$.
To see this, let $(w_n)$ be in $F$ and let $a=\sum_nw_n$.
Let $N$ be a natural number such that $w_n=0$ for $n\ge N$.
For $j\in\mathbb N$ let $z(j)$ be the element of $F'$ given by $z(j)_n=w_n$ if $n < N$ and $z(j)_n=-\frac 1j$ if $N\le j\le N+j-1$.
Then $\| z(j)-w\|=\sqrt{j |a|^2/j^2}=\sqrt{|a|^2/j}$ tends to zero, so $F'$ is dense in $F$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's nice. I just realizes for any proper dense submodule $F'$ is a counterexample.